# Custom Sort Order For Collection

Tags: magento-1.7, collection, model, resource-model, sorting

I need to sort a collection based on "sort_order" field instead of "id" as shown in the image.
[image]

```
$collection=Mage::getResourceModel('banners/manage_collection');
$collection->getSelect()->order('sort_order','DESC');
```

And

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423666/how-do-i-sort-magento-products-collection-with-order-by-field) but its always returns collection based on id field.

Answer (score 21):

You can add this code in the `__construct` method of your grid block after calling `parent::__construct();`:

```
$this->setDefaultSort('sort_order');
$this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
```

**EDIT**:
For frontend you can use this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('banners/manage_collection');
$collection->setOrder('sort_order','DESC');
```

Comment: I need to display the items in the front end based on the sort order.I am not sure above code will work?

Comment: @blakcaps. Then maybe you should state that in the question. You posted a screenshot of the backend so I assumed you want the default sorting in the backend by `sort_order`

Comment: @Marius default sorting happens based on one column. In my case first priority goes to status and the modified date. If there are 5 active and 5 inactive columns all 5 active records has to come first and earlier modified should come first within this 5, then 5 inactive latest modified first  within 5. How can I do that?